# How can I avoid "optimizing away" my javascript test cases?

Tags: javascript, benchmarking

I have a [jsperf test case](http://jsperf.com/multiplication-vs-division-lars), and the result are pretty confusing. I have three "snippets":

- multiplication
- division
- control (neither operation is done)

and most of the time, they all come out about the same speed... even the control! I guessed that the JS JIT compiler was [removing my "unnecessary" instructions](https://blog.mozilla.org/javascript/2014/07/15/ionmonkey-optimizing-away/) when they didn't seem to have any effect; so I started [accumulating the results, and logging them to the console](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4871762/423105) when the test loop is done, e.g.

```
for (var i = 0; i < nNumbers; i++) {
  result += a[i] / b[i];
}
console.log(result);
```

But then, I got wildly differing results when the console was open from when it wasn't. The slowdown from the console logging seemed to overwhelm any other performance issues.

So I tried cranking up the number of iterations within each "snippet," to minimize the amount of logging relative to the operations I'm trying to test. But I still get no significant speed difference between the three snippets. Really, division and multiplication are both about the same speed as evaluating a constant?? I must be doing something wrong. Or jsperf is broken.

There are related questions already answered, but none that I've found specific to Javascript benchmarking.

- [How can I prevent the Rust benchmark library from optimizing away my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32385805/how-can-i-prevent-the-rust-benchmark-library-from-optimizing-away-my-code)
- [How can I be sure that the compiler doesn't optimize away my performance test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871550/how-can-i-be-sure-that-the-compiler-doesnt-optimize-away-my-performance-test)

Comment: i got, ops a sec: mult:126k, div:33k, control: 282k, as expected since division is slow for computers. http://jsperf.com/multiplication-vs-division-lars/2

Comment: @dandavis I get similar results

Comment: that said, the chart didn't seem to be working right, but the numbers themselves were fine.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put `console.log`s in your timed sections. It's horribly slow in comparisons to the operations you actually want to measure, so it skews your results. Also - as you noticed - it varies in timing when the console is open or not.

You can prevent deoptimisations by putting your results in a global array. The optimiser can only [remove code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code_elimination) that does not affect the outcome, which is impossible if it manipulates global state.

Of course, this still does not necessarily prevent [loop-invariant code motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-invariant_code_motion), so you also need to make sure that your timed code always operates on different data.

Comment: Can you give an example of putting results in a global array? If I declare `var results;` in the `setup` code, is that a global variable, or do I have to put it in the Preparation code? Does it have to be an array as opposed to a single (scalar) variable? (As far as loop-invariant code is concerned, I believe my test snippets are already immune to this, as each iteration through the loop operates on `a[i]` and `b[i]`, where `i` is the loop variable.)

Comment: Putting the declaration in the setup code might suffice, but is not truly global - depends on how advanced the optimiser is. A scalar that you add to should work as well, but a scalar that you only overwrite probably won't.

Comment: I don't see a way to put results in a global variable. I tried moving the declaration of `result` (singular actually) out to the Preparation code (see http://jsperf.com/multiplication-vs-division-global-results) but now I get a `ReferenceError: result is not defined` in each snippet.

Comment: Next I tried using `window.result` as the global variable for results: `window.result += ...` in each snippet. This should be a global variable. However I still get odd results... division is now faster than multiplication (and control comes in first or last ... different each time).

Comment: Did you put the `var result` outside of the `<script>` tag on purpose? :-P

Comment: No, apparently that's what jsperf does with the Preparation code. Guess I should have added a script tag around it.

Comment: Now that I've put `<script>var result = 0;</script>` into the Preparation code, and am accumulating answers in `result` instead of `window.result`, the results seem plausible in relation to each other... although they're 10x faster than they were before. I guess the problem is solved.